# Controlling animation speed with requestAnimationFrame

Tags: javascript

I am trying to animate a square moving across the canvas from left to right. I am using requestAnimationFrame to do so. Unfortunately I am having trouble controlling the speed of the square.

My current code looks like so:

```
// Functions
// ===========================

// Square -> Square
// start the world with initial state s, e.g main(0)

function main(s) {
  requestAnimationFrame(main);
  advanceSquare(s);
  renderSquare(s);
}

// =========

// Square -> Square
// move square to the right

function advanceSquare(s) {
  s++;
}

// =========

// Square -> Image
// render the square on screen
// (check-expect)

function renderSquare(s) {
  renderScreen(screenWidth, screenHeight);
  ctx.fillStyle = squareColour;
  ctx.fillRect(s, squareYCoord, squareSides, squareSides);
}

// =========

// Number Number -> Image
// render the screen

function renderScreen(screenWidth, screenHeight) {
  ctx.fillStyle = screenColour;
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);
}
```

`s` represents the x-coordinate of the square. `advanceSquare(s)` increases `s` by 1. However, when I change `advanceSquare(s)` to:

```
function advanceSquare(s) {
  return s + 0.1;
}
```

the speed remains unchanged.

Are you able to suggest a way to slow down the speed of the square?

Thanks!

Comment: Here is an example where I measure the increment of time between requestAnimationFrames using the timestamp argument and calculate the rotation of the gear per the specified (dynamic) RPM per the time increment: https://codepen.io/sassano/pen/wvgxxMp.  You could similarly, after getting the time increment, send that to the advanceSquare function, which specifies what the new x coordinate should be per that period of time.

Comment: Do not assume a stable rate for requestAnimationFrame and even less an unique one for all your users. The previous comment has ot right, use a delta time to move your objects. Define speeds of each objects in px per seconds instead of px per frame.

Answer (score -1):

`requestAnimationFrame` runs at the frame rate i.e. 60fps. So your code is incrementing `s` 60 times per second. I bet that square is moving fast. You can add a global variable and increment that then use the modulo to slow down how many times `s` increments per second.

```
let counter = 0;

//change 20 to whatever speed you want
function advanceSquare(s) {
  if (counter % 20 == 0) s++;
}

//increment counter in the animation loop
function main(s) {
  counter++
  advanceSquare(s);
  renderSquare(s);
  requestAnimationFrame(main);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I discovered the issue with my code and there were 2 problems with it.

Firstly, The callback method for `requestAnimationFrame` is passed a single argument, a `DOMHighResTimeStamp`, which indicates the current time (based on the number of milliseconds since time origin). This means that we can't pass `s` into `main()`. Thus the code should be:

```
function main() {
  requestAnimationFrame(main);
  advanceSquare(s);
  renderSquare(s);
}
```

The second problem was that `renderSquare(s)` wasn't taking the updated value of `s` from `advanceSquare(s)`. In order to do this I had to write:

```
function main() {
  requestAnimationFrame(main);
  renderSquare(advanceSquare(s));
}
```